# jbutton.doClick() clicks the buttons but does not perform the function

Tags: java, swing, mouse

I have a jbutton which performs a function when clicked on by mouse. For doing this programatically I have this other function

```
void clickButton(){
      backButton.doClick();
}
```

When I run the clickButton() function I can see the backButton being pressed on the jFrame but the function associated with backButton does not happen. When I click on it with mouse it functions. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you reposting this question without demo code that shows the problem? I told you in your last posting there is nothing special about using the doClick() method, so you must have a problem with your code. Posting one line of code is useless for us to solve your problem. Post a SSCCE. If you don't know what a SSCCE is then use Google to search the web.

Comment: you should post more information about your problem. post the code where you assign the action (that you said doesn't work sometimes) to the button.

Comment: I believe that addActionListener doesn't quite work well, but addItemListener does, for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an `ActionListener` attached to your `button` it'll fire when you call the method `.doClick()`;

A sample test to prove it:

```
public class Test implements ActionListener {
    public Test() {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The action have been performed");
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        JButton but = new JButton();
        but.addActionListener(new Test());
        but.doClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the listeners for that button and call them manually.

```
    KeyEventDispatcher keyEventDispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
          @Override
          public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(final KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
              System.out.println(e);
              if (e.getKeyChar() == ' '){
                  MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(btnStop,MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,EventQueue.getMostRecentEventTime(),0,0,1,1,false);
                  for (MouseListener ml : btnStop.getMouseListeners()) ml.mouseClicked(me);
              }
            }
            // Pass the KeyEvent to the next KeyEventDispatcher in the chain
            return false;
          }
        };
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(keyEventDispatcher);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you attaching the logic to the button?  If you are using an [ActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) (or [Action](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html)) it should fire.  If you are using something else (perhaps MouseListener?), I don't think it will.